# Search LI list with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

greetings,

I have a bunch of `<li>` items inside a div, the div is scrollable

I would like to have a text box to mark the first li containing a certain text from a textbox and search button.

and the li should became visible :(

I have no clue how to do this :(

Comment: I have no clue as to what you want :(

Comment: I think you want something like jQuery UI autocomplete?  http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: @Pedro Correia: I want to highlight a li that contains a text I put on the search text box

@superUntitled: That's a good help already but still I need to highlight the LI and scroll the div until it appears :S

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Live Demo Updated with scrolling](http://jsfiddle.net/u4Egq/1/)**

**Markup**

```
<div id='test'>
    <ul>
         <li>Text</li>
         <li>Something</li>
         <li>Hey</li> 
         <li>der</li>
         <li>herp</li>
         <li>derp</li>
         <li>Testing</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#searchBtn').click(function(){
    var searchString = $('#searchText').val(),
        foundLi = $('li:contains("' + searchString + '")');

    foundLi.addClass('found');
    $('#test').animate({ scrollTop: foundLi.offset().top});
});
```

Comment: Note that the "contains" selector used that way will break if the search string contains certain characters

Comment: You'll want to make sure you also clear the results when you hit submit. Otherwise once a LI is selected it will always be selected even if it does not match the current search term. 


here is a slightly adjusted version with search on keyup().
http://jsfiddle.net/7A5NX/4/

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the scrollTo plugin: http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html
then do something like this (not tested)

```
$('#thediv').scrollTo( $('li:contains("'+yourtext+'")') );
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML:

```
<div style="height: 40px; overflow-y: scroll" id="my_div">
    <li>the first li</li>
    <li>the second li</li>
    <li>the third li</li>
    <li>the fourth li</li>
    ...
</div>

<input type="text" id="my_text_box" />
<input type="submit" id="my_search_button" />
```

The javascript:

```
$('#my_search_button').click(function(e) {
    var my_search = $('#my_text_box').val(); // the text to search for
    var $my_div = $('#my_div'); // the div
    $my_div.find('li').each(function(idx, elem) {
      $elem = $(elem);
      if ($elem.text().indexOf(my_search) != -1) { // if it contains your searched text
        $elem.show(); // display it ? only if needed, unclear from question
        $elem.addClass('highlighted'); // add your class for the highlight
        $my_div.scrollTop($elem.position().top); // scroll to it
        return false; // stop the loop
      }
    });

    e.preventDefault(); // stop an actual form from being submitted
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for something similar:

Visitors to my site should be able to search within a clickable list of locations (for local weather report).

Ideally, there should be a match mechanism:

as the visitor begins entering the name of the location, that name should be suggested automatically in the search field.

Is there any code like that?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out https://github.com/svapreddy/cssListJS.

Search functionality implemented using pure CSS and little bit JS