# Validate user input if it matches the text of an anchor tag using the native js

Tags: javascript, html

i have a form field:
1 - input text and a button...

```
<form action="#">
   <input type="text" id="desc" value="">
   <input name="submit" tabindex="1" value="Update" type="submit" onclick="validate()">            
</form>
```

and here are my anchor tags

```
<ul>        
    <li><a class="gen"  href="#"> Jan</a></li>
    <li><a class="gen"  href="#"> Feb </a></li>
    <li><a class="gen"  href="#"> March </a></li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way in javascript to check the value of input and match against the value of an anchor tag?

If there is a match, then `alert(match)`. If not, then `alert(not)`?

Case-insensitive --  if the input value is `"jan"` or `"jAn"` it still matches.

Comment: Do you want to validate against the text (not the value, `a` tags don't have values) of *all* the anchors in the document? Or only those with a certain class, or in a certain container? And do you also want to trim the whitespace around the text in those anchors? It appears so, but the question is far from clear.

Comment: ... and, of course, [please show us what you've tried so far](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Your question is already contain ans http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154022/search-li-list-with-jquery and fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/u4Egq/1/

Comment: i want to get the text in anchor tag using their class.. I dont know how to do it.. I am newbie sir.. Can you help me with this,, using the javascipt

Comment: Its very disappointing that people are not willing to use the best they have for their work....I will still keep posting my answers with a better approach.. And I have learnt the same from one of the moderator of stack overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be a pure JavaScript solution

```
function validate(){
    var val = document.getElementById("desc").value.trim().toLowerCase();
    var a_list = document.getElementsByClassName("gen");
    var content;
    for(var i=0;i<a_list.length;i++){
        content = a_list[i].innerHTML.trim().toLowerCase();
        if(content == val){
            alert('match');
            return;
        }
    }
    alert('no match');
    return;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wpercy/2he9rwab/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following code

```js
$("#valid").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var f = 0;
  $(".gen").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().trim() === $("#desc").val().toLowerCase().trim()) {
      f = 1;
      alert("match");
    }

  });
  if (f == 0)
    alert("No Match");


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <input type="text" id="desc" value="">
  <input name="submit" id="valid" tabindex="1" value="Update" type="submit">
</form>
and here is the my anchor tag

<ul class="tags">
  <li><a class="gen a" href="#"> Jan</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="gen" href="#"> Feb </a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="gen" href="#"> March </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: is there a way not using jquery sir??

Comment: @Bee What you want to use then ? Please specify ?

Answer (score 0):

```
function validate() {
    var flag = false;
    var x = document.getElementById("desc");
    x = x.value;
    var y = document.getElementsByClassName("gen");
    for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
        if(x.toLowerCase().trim() == y[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().trim()){
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    if (flag) {
        alert("y");
    } else {
        alert("n");
    }
}
```

Here you go. This should work.